# How to install radeon-crimson-15.11-15.30.1025 in ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: ati

I want Install radeon-crimson-15.11-15.30.1025 but I dont know how. I want to play dota 2. when I switch in additional driver from X.org X server to fglrx update, dota2 was crash when loading screen to play the game. please help me

Answer (score 1):

First uninstall all previously attempted driver intallation by running

```
sudo sh /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx*
```

If you driver wasn't manually installed then you can skip the first command.
Make sure universe and multiverse are enabled in your repository sources by going

> (System -> Administration -> Software Sources).

AMD driver needs some prerequisite packages to be installed.

For 32-bit system run

```
sudo apt-get install cdbs dh-make dkms execstack dh-modaliases linux-headers-generic libqtgui4 xserver-xorg-dev-lts-trusty
```

For 64-bit system run

```
sudo apt-get install lib32gcc1
```

Now downlod the Crimson Driver

```
mkdir catalyst15.11 && cd catalyst15.11
wget --referer='http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Linux+x86' http://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/radeon-crimson-15.11-15.30.1025.zip
unzip radeon-crimson-15.11-15.30.1025.zip
cd fglrx-15.30.1025/
```

Create and install .deb packages

```
chmod a+x amd-driver-installer-15.30.1025-x86.x86_64.run
sudo ./amd-driver-installer-15.30.1025-x86.x86_64.run --buildpkg Ubuntu/trusty
sudo dpkg -i fglrx*.deb
```